# Centre align in php file

Tags: php, css

I have the following script acting as a menu page. The user's details are verified and they then have the option of clicking on one of the three tours. To tidy it up i want to centralise the text. However, so far, when i centralise the text the hyperlinks no longer work, it says that 'move1.php' cannot be found, i have tried different methods, and with another solution, if the text is centralised, some of the functions on the next php script do not work. How would i centralise the text but not affect the php scripts or hyperlinks. Thanks

```
<?php    
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

echo "Click here to see your <a href=\"move1.php\">Redbus tour 1!</a>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "Click here to see your <a href=\"move2.php\">Redbus tour 2!</a>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "Click here to see your <a href=\"move1.php\">Redbus tour 3!</a>";


 } else {

//No- jump to log in page.
header("location: login.php");
exit();
 }
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean "center" the text, or "centralise" the text in a PHP file?

Answer (score 7):

Try centering with css

Wrap text in div and align text center

```
<?php    
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

echo "<div style=\"text-align:center\">";
echo "Click here to see your <a href=\"move1.php\">Redbus tour 1!</a>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "Click here to see your <a href=\"move2.php\">Redbus tour 2!</a>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "Click here to see your <a href=\"move1.php\">Redbus tour 3!</a>";
echo "</div>";

 } else {

//No- jump to log in page.
header("location: login.php");
exit();
 }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Simple as that huh. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<center>` tag in HTML

```
<?php    
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

echo "<center>";
echo "Click here to see your <a href=\"move1.php\">Redbus tour 1!</a>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "Click here to see your <a href=\"move2.php\">Redbus tour 2!</a>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "Click here to see your <a href=\"move1.php\">Redbus tour 3!</a>";
echo "</center>";


 } else {

//No- jump to log in page.
header("location: login.php");
exit();
 }
?>
```